# How to load the XML files from directory please

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

This code I got somewhere on internet and I edited it.

How can I load the XML file from my directory? Is there any way to do this?

```
from elementtree import ElementTree as et
# Load the xml content from a string
content = et.fromstring("C:\DATA\US_Patent_Data\2012\ipgb20120103_wk01\ipgb20120103.xml")


# Get the person or use the .findall method to get all
# people if there's more than person
applicant = content.find("applicant")
last_name = applicant.find("addressbook/last-name")
first_name = applicant.find("addressbook/first-name")

# Get the persons address
address = addressbook.find("address")
street = address.find("street")
city= address.find("city")
state =  address.find("state")
postcode = address.find("postcode")
country = address.find("country")

# Print output
print "sequence: " + applicant.attrib.get('sequence')
print "first name: " + first_name.text
print "last name: " + last_name.text
print "street: " + street.text
print "city: " + city.text
print "state: " + state.text
print "postcode: " + postcode.text
print "country: " + country.text
```

I ran the program this is what I got.
I copied part of them...

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\elementtree\ElementTree.py", line 1292, in feed
self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
```

ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromstring` function is for reading xml data from string.

For reading xml data from file you should use `parse`. See [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) on parsing xml with elementtree.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("C:\DATA\US_Patent_Data\2012\ipgb20120103_wk01\ipgb20120103.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
```

UPD: 
Seems like your xml is not well-formed because it has multiple roots. Try adding a single root element:

```
with open('ipgb20120103.xml', 'r') as f:
    xml_string = "<root>%s</root>" % f.read()

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
```

Comment: it says something like this.`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\DATA\\US_Patent_Data\x812\\ipgb20120103_wk01\\ipgb20120103.xml'` Whenever I use etree.parse, I always get something like that

Comment: It's ridiculously strange how 2012 can be changed to x812. I think it changes the path... I have moved the files to desktop, now it gives me different error
`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\elementtree\ElementTree.py", line 1292, in feed
   self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
ExpatError: junk after document element: line 414, column 0`

Comment: The XML has more roots for example it has repetition of`<us-patent-grant>` but only after it closes the tag, then it has the startTag again...

Comment: The full error is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfilepath", line 3, in <module>
    tree = et.parse("ipgb20120103.xml")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\elementtree\ElementTree.py", line 908, in parse
    tree = parser_api.parse(source)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\elementtree\ElementTree.py", line 174, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\elementtree\ElementTree.py", line 1292, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
ExpatError: junk after document element: line 414`

Comment: Do you think there are any possibilities to do add the single root element using Python Script? @alexander